# excel vba userform enableevents

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with Excel VBA UserForm Events in Office Excel 2013 as follows

1. Simple userform with three check boxes (CB1,2,3) and two buttons Cancel and OK
2. When checking CB1 set CB3 = false
3. When checking CB2 set CB3 = false
4. When checking CB3 set CB1 = false and CB2 = false

I have read and understood http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm regarding the suppression of UserForm Events and to part it works...

In the list above 2. and 3. above work correctly in code (shown below) and no-events are fired for CB3.  However when I do 4. Check CB3 - it fires events for CB1 and CB2, even though I have set it to not fire events.

Any help gratefully received,

Best regards

Seán

Code:

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub vboInputsSelected_Click()

    Me.EnableEvents = False
    vboPracticesSelected.value = False           'this line does NOT fire an event
    Me.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub vboOutputsSelected_Click()

    Me.EnableEvents = False
    vboPracticesSelected.value = False           'this line does NOT fire an event
    Me.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub vboPracticesSelected_Click()

    Me.EnableEvents = False
    vboInputsSelected.value = False           'this line DOES fire an event
    vboOutputsSelected.value = False          'this line DOES fire an event
    Me.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you not need to set each check box's value instead of just assigning true or false to the object?

Comment: Thanks Nick, good point, I have changed the code to be correct: with the .value on the end (vboInputsSelected.value = False) and it STILL fires an event when EnableEvents is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well for me. The `If` bails out when an event is in progress. Realize that the `EnableEvents` variable does nothing on its own to prevent events. It is only a boolean you created. You need to check it, before allowing an event to occur, for it to do anything.

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub vboInputsSelected_Click()
  If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub

  Me.EnableEvents = False
  vboPracticesSelected.Value = False
  Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub vboOutputsSelected_Click()
  If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub

  Me.EnableEvents = False
  vboPracticesSelected.Value = False
  Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub vboPracticesSelected_Click()
  If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub

  Me.EnableEvents = False
  vboInputsSelected.Value = False
  vboOutputsSelected.Value = False
  Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want there to always be a box selected, you can set each box to true inside of its own `Click` event (between the `EnabledEvents`), and there will always be one true box.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reference](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/19036/best-practices):

> it's a better practice to work with a new instance of the class

Below **trying** to adapt the code:

```
'http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm
'https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/19036/best-practices
Private Type TView
    IsCancelled As Boolean
    EnableEvents As Boolean
End Type
Private this As TView
Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = this.IsCancelled
End Property
Public Property Get EnableEvents() As Boolean
    EnableEvents = this.EnableEvents
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'...
this.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
On Error GoTo ExceptionHandling
this.EnableEvents = False

'some code that would cause an event to run

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    this.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ExceptionHandling:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.description & vbLf & Err.Number
    Resume CleanUp
    Resume 'for debugging
End Sub 

Private Sub TextBox2_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'check example
If this.EnableEvents = False Then Cancel = True
'some code to run
End Sub 

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        this.IsCancelled = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

**See Also**

[VBA UserForm – A Guide for Everyone, Paul Kelly](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/)